# How to print ASCII Art to console in Free Pascal?

Tags: console, ascii, freepascal

I have a text which contains a piece of ASCII art. How can I print it to a console in Free Pascal? I know that it would be easier in other program languages, but I am only allowed to use Free Pascal.

Writing it with multiple writeln() for each line would be too exhausting.
Is there another way to do it?

```
                                                     (\\( \
                                                      `.\-.)
                                  _...._            _,-'   `-.
    \                           ,'      `-._.---.,-'       .  \
     \`.                      ,'                               `.
      \ `-...__              /                           .   .:  y
       `._     ``--..__     /                           ,'`---._/
          `-._         ``--'                      |    /_
              `.._                   _            ;   <_ \
                  `--.___             `.           `-._ \ \
                         `--<           `.     (\ _/)/ `.\/
                             \            \     `<a \  /_/
                              `.           ;      `._y
                                `--.      /    _../
                                    \    /__..'
                                     ;  //
                                    <   \\
                                     `.  \\
                                       `. \\_ __
                                         `.`-'  \\
                                           `----''  hjw
```

Comment: `Write(text);` // assuming text contains line breaks

Comment: `WriteLn('Some arty characters'#13#10 + 'More characters on next line'#13#10 + 'And so on'); `

Comment: You say you have text. Do you mean a text file? If so stream it in (for example to a TStringList via LoadFromFile) and then print out a line at a time - a simple for loop will do.

Comment: Write it in another programming language, which would be easier, then convert it to pascal - which, probably, wouldn't be hard.

Comment: @Dsm: TStringList.Text contains newlines where necessary, so Writeln(MyStringList.Text) should do. No need for an explicit loop.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file is called *ASCII_ART.txt*, then do something like:

```pascal
program DisplayASCIIArt;

uses
  Classes;

var
  SL: TStringList;

begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    SL.LoadFromFile('ASCII_ART.txt'); // use real name (full path!) here.
    Writeln(SL.Text);
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
  // if the console window closes immediately, add the following two lines:
  Write('Press [ENTER] key...');
  Readln;
end.
```